# Живет ли динамическая переменная за функией?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, память

Я начал изучать динамическое выделение памяти, в первую очередь я разобрался с динамическими массивами, с ними все ясно, их мы используем например когда заранее размер не известен. Но я заинтересовался динамическими переменными(а не массивами), посмотрел в интернете и нашел такую вещь:

```
void foo() {
 int variable = 5; //lives only in function
 int *dVariable = new int(5); //lives outside function

}
```

И на многих сайтах приводят именно этот пример, но я не понимаю как же это переменная живет вне функции? я попробовал сделать тоже самое, и попытался обратиться к переменной dVariable вне функции(например в main) естественно получаю ошибку, объясните пожалуйста как же все таки к ней обратиться если она живет вне функции? Или я просто неправильно понимаю слово "Живет вне функции"?

Comment: вы путаете имя переменной и память выделенную под нее. Вы не можете обратится к переменной за пределами ее области видимости, но выделенная память так и остается висеть - это пример `leak memory`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а я могу обратиться и работать с данной памятью вне функции?

Comment: если коротко, то да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не

```
int dVariable = new int(5);
```

а

```
int *dVariable = new int(5);
```

Если вы вернете указатель из функции - то эта память будет доступна и далее. Например,

```
int * foo() 
{
    int * ptr = new int(5);
    return ptr;
}

.....

int * v = foo();
cout << *v << endl;
```

будет выведена ваша пятерка. Память остается выделенной, пока вы где-то (возможно, в очень далеком месте) не освободите ее с помощью `delete`.

Так стало понятнее?

Comment: А если я буду менять значение переменной v (например напишу *v = 10) то у меня эта 10 запишется именно в ту память которая выделилась под 5?

Comment: Да, конечно. Считайте, что это адрес обычной переменной :)